# Convert centimetres to feet and inches

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm trying to write a function which converts `cm` to `feet` and `inches`

```
cmToFtIn(30) === {"feet": 1, "inches": 0}
cmToFtIn(29) === {"feet": 0, "inches": 11}
```

What I've done already is this complicated function

```
const cmToFeetMultiplier = multiply(1/30.5)
const ftToInMultiplier = multiply(12)
const floor = (num) => Math.floor(num)
const round = (num) => Math.round(num)
const cmToFtIn = pipe(
   cmToFeetMultiplier,
   juxt([identity, floor]),
   juxt([identity, pipe(apply(subtract), ftToInMultiplier, round)]),
   flatten,
   cond([
     [pipe(nth(2), equals(12)), (d) => ({feet: d[1] + 1, inches: 0})],
     [always(true), (d) => ({feet: d[1], inches: d[2]})],
   ])
  )
```

Maybe someone has some advice as to how to simplify it?

[Playground](https://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20cmToFeetMultiplier%20%3D%20multiply%281%2F30.5%29%0Aconst%20ftToInMultiplier%20%3D%20multiply%2812%29%0Aconst%20floor%20%3D%20%28num%29%20%3D%3E%20Math.floor%28num%29%0Aconst%20round%20%3D%20%28num%29%20%3D%3E%20Math.round%28num%29%0Aconst%20cmToFtIn%20%3D%20pipe%28%0A%20%20%20cmToFeetMultiplier%2C%0A%20%20%20juxt%28%5Bidentity%2C%20floor%5D%29%2C%0A%20%20%20juxt%28%5Bidentity%2C%20pipe%28apply%28subtract%29%2C%20ftToInMultiplier%2C%20round%29%5D%29%2C%0A%20%20%20flatten%2C%0A%20%20%20cond%28%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%5Bpipe%28nth%282%29%2C%20equals%2812%29%29%2C%20%28d%29%20%3D%3E%20%28%7Bfeet%3A%20d%5B1%5D%20%2B%201%2C%20inches%3A%200%7D%29%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%5Balways%28true%29%2C%20%28d%29%20%3D%3E%20%28%7Bfeet%3A%20d%5B1%5D%2C%20inches%3A%20d%5B2%5D%7D%29%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%5D%29%0A%20%20%29%0A%0AcmToFtIn%2830%29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you google "cm to inch":

[image]

and "cm to foot":

[image]

We can then build a `inch` and `foot` functions:

```
const inch = flip(divide)(2.54);
const foot = flip(divide)(30.48);

inch(30); //=> 11.811023622047244
foot(30); //=> 0.984251968503937
```

If you need to return an object `{inch, foot}` from a value in *cm* you can without Ramda:

```
const cmToFtIn = cm => ({inch: inch(cm), foot: foot(cm)});

cmToFtIn(30);
//=> {"foot": 0.984251968503937, "inch": 11.811023622047244}
```

With Ramda:

```
const cmToFtIn = applySpec({inch, foot});

cmToFtIn(30);
//=> {"foot": 0.984251968503937, "inch": 11.811023622047244}
```

Personally I'd recommend that you do not return rounded values directly from `inch` and `foot` functions. You can apply a second pass to round them where you need to do so. Two options:

Apply `Math.round` on your `{inch, foot}` object:

```
map(Math.round, cmToFtIn(30));
//=> {"foot": 1, "inch": 12}
```

Or compose `Math.round` and `inch`/`foot` functions:

```
const cmToFtIn = applySpec({
  inch: compose(Math.round, inch),
  foot: compose(Math.round, foot)
});

cmToFtIn(30);
//=> {"foot": 1, "inch": 12}
```

Comment: thanks. Almost exactly what I want. Forgot about `applySpec`. And what if we want to go further. Not to display inches if it `% by 12`, should I use `cond` in
`const divideBy12 = v => v % 12 === 0;
const round = cond([
  [divideBy12, always(0)],
  [always(true), always(identity)],
]);
`
`inch: compose(round, Math.round, inch),` ?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand this. Do you mean to have only `{foot}` (or `{inch}`) if either `foot` (or `inch`) divided by `12` equals zero?

Comment: i mean if want to achive this result `cmToFtIn(30) === {"feet": 1, "inches": 0}` not this `{"foot": 1, "inch": 12}`

Answer (score 2):

Unless this is an exercise to learn Ramda, I would suggest that Ramda is not the right tool for this job.  I'm one of the authors of Ramda, and a big fan, but it's a tool designed to help make an FP style more palatable in JS, not a general-purpose utility library.

The issue is that this function can be written quite simply in vanilla JS:

```js
const cmToInFt = (cm, inches = Math .round (cm / 2.54)) => ({
  feet: Math .floor (inches / 12),
  inches: inches % 12
})

const myHeight = cmToInFt (185)

console .log (myHeight)
```

Or, if you don't like default parameters, it might be:

```js
const cmToInFt = (cm) => {
  const inches = Math .round (cm / 2.54)
  return {
    feet: Math .floor (inches / 12), 
    inches: inches % 12
  }
}
```

Ramda can add little to that.  Obviously, as your approach and customcommander's answer show, you can use Ramda functions to help, and a little dose of `compose` is often useful.  But this (which is very similar to the answer from Aadit M Shah, structured slightly differently) is already clean and readable.  I see little that will make it easier to work with.

Comment: Also, a big fan of ramda, thank you for your work:) In this case, I will definitely skip my variant in favor of one from answers.

Answer (score 1):

There are `2.54` centimeters in an inch. Hence, we have the equation.

```js
const cmToInches = cm => cm / 2.54;
```

There are `12` inches in a foot. Hence, we have the equation.

```js
const inchesToFtIn = inches => ({
  feet: Math.floor(inches / 12),
  inches: inches % 12,
});
```

Now, to convert centimeters to feet and inches we just compose these two functions.

```js
const cmToInches = cm => cm / 2.54;

const inchesToFtIn = inches => ({
  feet: Math.floor(inches / 12),
  inches: inches % 12,
});

const cmToFtIn = cm => inchesToFtIn(cmToInches(cm));

console.log(cmToFtIn(30.48)); // 1 foot
console.log(cmToFtIn(27.94)); // 11 inches
```

If you need to round the inches then that's a small change.

```js
const cmToInches = cm => cm / 2.54;

const inchesToFtIn = inches => ({
  feet: Math.floor(inches / 12),
  inches: inches % 12,
});

const cmToFtIn = cm => inchesToFtIn(Math.round(cmToInches(cm)));

console.log(cmToFtIn(30)); // 1 foot
console.log(cmToFtIn(29)); // 11 inches
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. Almost what I want except small detail. 
I need round numbers in asuch way
`cmToFtIn(30) === {"feet": 1, "inches": 0}` not `{"feet":0,"inches":11.811023622047244}`

Comment: You can simply add the `Math.round` function in between the `inchesToFtIn` and `cmToInches` functions. I edited my answer to demonstrate that.